# <strong> vs. font-weight:bold & <em> vs. font-style:italic

Tags: html, css

Is there any real difference between using `<strong>` and `<em>` instead of the CSS properties:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
```

Also, what is really the reason that both options exist? I could be wrong but didn't `<strong>` and `<em>` came on the scene quite a while after `font-weight` and `font-style` became standard CSS properties? If so, there must be some reason for them.

Comment: comparing `strong` to `font-weight: bold` is like comparing `h1` to `display: block; font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; margin: .67em 0;`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

HTML represents meaning; CSS represents appearance. How you mark up text in a document is not determined by how that text appears on screen, but simply what it means. As another example, some other HTML elements, like headings, are styled `font-weight: bold` by default, but they are marked up using `<h1>`–`<h6>`, not `<strong>` or `<b>`.

In HTML5, you use [`<strong>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) to indicate important parts of a sentence, for example:

```
<p><strong>Do not touch.</strong> Contains <strong>hazardous</strong> materials.
```

And you use [`<em>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) to indicate linguistic stress, for example:

```
<p>A Gentleman: I suppose he does. But there's no point in asking.
<p>A Lady: Why not?
<p>A Gentleman: Because he doesn't row.
<p>A Lady: He doesn't <em>row</em>?
<p>A Gentleman: No. He <em>doesn't</em> row.
<p>A Lady: Ah. I see what you mean.
```

These elements are semantic elements that just happen to have **bold** and *italic* representations by default, but you can style them however you like. For example, in the `<em>` sample above (dialogue from the opening scene of BioShock Infinite), you could represent [stress emphasis in uppercase instead of italics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Cb96qvTWGI#t=1m3s), but the functional purpose of the `<em>` element remains the same — to change the context of a sentence by emphasizing specific words or phrases over others:

```css
em {
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```css
em {
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>A Gentleman: I suppose he does. But there's no point in asking.
<p>A Lady: Why not?
<p>A Gentleman: Because he doesn't row.
<p>A Lady: He doesn't <em>row</em>?
<p>A Gentleman: No. He <em>doesn't</em> row.
<p>A Lady: Ah. I see what you mean.
```

Note that the original answer from 2011 (below) applied to HTML standards prior to HTML5, in which `<strong>` and `<em>` had somewhat different meanings, [`<b>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) and [`<i>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) were purely presentational and had no semantic meaning whatsoever. Like `<strong>` and `<em>` respectively, they have similar presentational defaults but may be styled differently.

---

You use `<strong>` and `<em>` to indicate intense emphasis and normal emphasis respectively.

Or think of it this way: `font-weight: bold` is closer to `<b>` than `<strong>`, and `font-style: italic` is closer to `<i>` than `<em>`. These visual styles are purely *visual*: tools like screen readers aren't going to understand what **bold** and *italic* mean, but some screen readers are able to read `<strong>` and `<em>` text in a more emphasized tone.

Comment: This isn't just theoretical, either — it's not all that uncommon for underlines, text colors and background colors to be used instead of the default styling.

Answer (score 11):

## The `<em>` element - from W3C (HTML5 reference)

YES! There is a clear difference.

The `<em>` element **represents stress emphasis of its contents**. The level of emphasis that a particular piece of content has is given by its number of ancestor `<em>` elements.

```
<strong>  =  important content
<em>      =  stress emphasis of its contents
```

*The placement of emphasis changes the meaning of the sentence. The element thus forms an integral part of the content. The precise way in which emphasis is used in this way depends on the language.*

### Note!

1. The `<em>` element also isnt intended to convey importance; for that
   purpose, the `<strong>` element is more appropriate.
2. The `<em>` element isn't a generic "italics" element. Sometimes, text
   is intended to stand out from the rest of the paragraph, as if it was
   in a different *mood* or *voice*. For this, the `i` element is more
   appropriate.

Reference (examples): [See W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-em-element.html#the-em-element)

Comment: `<strong>` and `<em>` are _semantic_ markup. Instead of just saying `<b>` or `<i>`, you're giving a "reason" why it's marked differently -- more information about the text than a simple stylistic markup like `<b>` or `<i>`. This can be very important for screen readers, as a simple `<i>` could mean emphasis, a foreign word, a cited title, etc. `<em>` is usually visually equivalent to `<i>` (and `<strong>` to `<b>`), but that's not guaranteed, and can be changed in CSS.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is an issue of semantic meaning (as BoltClock mentions) and visual rendering.

Originally HTML used `<b>` and `<i>` for these purposes, entirely stylistic commands, laid down in the semantic environment of the document markup.  CSS is an attempt to separate out as far as possible the stylistic elements of the medium.  Thus style information such as bold and italics should go in CSS.

`<strong>` and `<em>` were introduced to fill the semantic need for text to be marked as more important or stressed.  They have default stylistic interpretations akin to **bold** and *italic*, but they are not bound to that fate.

Answer (score 2):

`<strong>` and `<em>` - unlike `<b>` and `<i>` - have clear purpose for web browsers for the blind.

A blind person doesn't browse the web visually, but by sound such as text readers. `<strong>` and `<em>`, in addition to encouraging something to be bold or italic, also convey loudness or stressing syllables respectively (OH MY! & Ooooooh Myyyyyyy!). Audio-only browsers are unpredictable when it comes to `<b>` and `<i>`... they may make them loud or stress them or they may not... you never can be sure unless you use `<strong>` and `<em>`.