# Which is more appropriate for marking up the property in a property/value pair: <strong> or font-weight:bold?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble deciding whether to use `<strong>` or `font-weight:bold` in the following situation. There is a list of various properties of a school. Each list item is the property name in bold, followed by the property value for this specific school. I understand that `<strong>` is used to emphasize a word or phrase in the context of the surrounding text, but I can't decide if a property name correctly fits that designation.

Here are the two options:

```
<!-- The class bold sets the font-weight to bold -->
<li><span class="bold">Setting:</span> Suburban</li>
```

or

```
<li><strong>Setting:</strong> Suburban</li>
```

Comment: [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939807/strong-vs-font-weightbold-em-vs-font-styleitalic) is a question whose answer addresses this well.

Comment: @Darth I saw that question but wasn't sure how it applied to this specific situation.

Comment: A rule of thumb I sometimes consider:  Would you want a screen reader to emphasize the word 'Setting'?  If so, then use <strong>, otherwise, use styles.

Comment: It would become a real question if you defined criteria for appropriateness. Asked abstractly, it just asks for opinions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `<span>`, use a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)!

Then you can style the `<dt>`s with `font-weight: bold` if they're not already.

Here's a sample of how it's used (thanks to the others who posted it!):

```
<dl>
    <dt>Setting</dt>
    <dd>Suburban</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're marking up a list of property/value pairs, you might want to consider the [`<dl>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) instead:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Setting:</dt>
    <dd>Suburban</dd>
</dl>
```

This actually indicates that "Setting:" is a label for "Suburban".

Answer (score 2):

I would say that semantically both options are bad as there is a problem with your markup. Sounds like what you need is a `dl` tag instead of an `ul` or `ol` as you have a list of name - value pairs here.

```
<dl>
  <dt>Setting:</dt>
  <dd>Suburban</dd>
</dl>
```

Good description on the `dl` can be found here - http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/

Answer (score 0):

This is totally based on your preferences. See `<strong>` and `font-weight:bold` ultimately does almost the same thing visually(unless you explicitly specify css for strong).

The difference comes in view when you try to create your mark-up semantically correct and more readable.

With `<strong>` you will have to write a little less and the mark-up will be more readable I think.

Comment: "See <strong> and font-weight:bold ultimately does the same thing." That's not really true. `<strong>` indicates that the content should be emphasised. `font-weight:bold` indicates that it should be displayed with a bold font. Those two aren't the same thing.

Comment: thats what i tried to mean by the same work. anyways edited the answer.