# Why do we need Italic/Bold Font Files? What is the difference between HTML Italic/Strong tag and a Font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Why do we need italic/bold font files if we have <em> <strong> that can italicize and bold respectively ?

Arial Narrow Italic
Arial Narrow Italic Bold

Is there a special scenario where having the file can actually make it more perfect than what browser can render ? For example browser might have a generic way of making italic vs bold however a specific italic/bold file could make it much better ?

How do I actually use them in the application ? For example I need Caslon 540
Caslon 540 italic , and I get two files for both . Do I treat them as entirely different font like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Caslon;
  src: url(fonts/Caslon.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: CaslonItalic;
  src: url(fonts/CaslonItalic.ttf);
}
```

This looks simpler to implement ?

or do I actually have one Font with differnet font:style specification ?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Caslon;
  src: url(fonts/Caslon.ttf);
    }

@font-face {
  font-family: Caslon;
  src: url(fonts/CaslonItalic.ttf);
  font-style: italics;
}
```

Does this have an overhead that you need to have a font-style:italics embedded into each element's html attribute or would  automatically detect that its CaslonItalics ?

There is a somewhat similar question in its essence here : [<strong> vs. font-weight:bold & <em> vs. font-style:italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939807/strong-vs-font-weightbold-em-vs-font-styleitalic)

Comment: They aren't true italics or bold unless you use the specific font.

Comment: When you say "true italics" what do you mean ? How would I use them correctly ? Is 1 or 2 option better - any thoughts ?

Comment: They may have stylistic changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face?rq=1

Comment: @Nishant If you don't supply proper font faces for italic, bold, or any stylized texts, user agent mimics their stylized appearance. So, there may be stylistic differences. https://spaceninja.com/2010/11/29/font-face-faux-styles/ This might be helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The end-user's browser may not have the font installed.  Remember, the content is being rendered *client*-side, not server-side.
2. There may be something about your content that requires some aspect of the specific typeface (odd kerning, specific sizes available, special characters, *etc.*) for best readability.
3. The `<i>`, `<em>`, *etc*, HTML tags don't do anything to the typeface at all -- they tell the *client* how they should be rendered, and the client chooses the appropriate typeface.
4. You can use CSS to tell the rendering engine to use a particular typeface for italics, like `i, em { font-family: Caslon; }'`.  This is discouraged, though, because you're taking choice away from the reader -- who may not *like* your typeface choice.

Comment: Yes I will deploy it using URL / Data URI . Thanks I will go through this to understand this in depth . Its subtle sometimes .