# Font-weight vs <strong> vs <b> [ SEO, Semantics ]

Tags: html, css, seo

Ok, I need some clarification here.

1) Is the only difference between `<b>` and `<strong>` tags are the fact that `<strong>` used for some browsers that don't support css-styling? Like accessibility browsers etc? If not, what the heck else is this needed, because otherwise I don't understand the meaning of "semantics" or the "meaning" to use the `<strong>` instead of `<b>`.

2) Is there a difference between the `<b>` or `<strong>` tags and `font-weight:bold` in terms of SEO?

The theoretical and practical sides are both interesting for this two above questions.

Thanks

Comment: kindly refer to this link. You get your answer. [Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939839/5971348)

Comment: Look here [stack link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)

Comment: @ZeeshanAfzalSatti No I don't

Comment: @Relisora SEO not revealed; My first question is based exactly on this kind of answers

Comment: SEO questions are [**off-topic**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281367/where-to-find-answers-to-seo-questions) for Stack Overflow

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Comment: @Paulie_D Interesting... So thinking of a `<b>` as `font-weight:bold`, means I should **not** use styling for it, but instead use `<strong>` and apply `css` styles for it? Also, Mozilla based on their logic of understanding things, is it actually apply for global browser share - is it the same as for mozilla at this point?

Comment: MDN is the go-to reference (other than the actual HTML specififcations) for all developers not just the Firefox browser.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok. And as for the `font-weight: bold` and `<b>` tag, am I getting it right or it works differently(say, because the code is a `css`, the `font-weight: bold` is applied differently than `<b>` tag etc)

Comment: @kez unless you have a really good reason to use b/i instead of strong/em you should stick with strong/em. Text readers and devices that default to bolding text for readability treat them different. If a blind person is reading a site a b tag doesn't do anything, nor does an i tag. Strong/em are called out by the reader though. So eventually I would expect that SEO will weigh those more heavily. Our only info about SEO not doing so is a decade old at this point and SEO is way more advanced now than it was in 2006.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same regarding SEO, but its good to know what is the difference between them.

Matt Cutts from Google talked about this topic in 2006 and made another video about it, both are the same, on of them are used in the HTML and the other one is used inside the WYSIWYG editors.

You can use them both and all the browsers and search engines will understand them, and here is the video by Matt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awto_wCeOJ4

Comment: I question this still being accurate. It's 10 years old at this point and google tends towards making things more available to disabled and to devices, which strong/em is vs b/i... Unfortunately it seems like the most recent info that we have. So even if it isn't 100% accurate, if google has weighed strong/em heavier than b/i, they haven't done it in a way that seems measurable to the people that pay attention to these things.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep in mind that SEO optimisation is changing with time and depends
>   about search engine you use.

Today, and for the articles I found, I would say that `strong`and `b` are treated exactly the same in term of SEO.

Using one or the other **should** not affect your Google ranking.

Comment: Two things: SEO, not "CEO". And another note: `strong` is used for semantic, not the `b`

Comment: nice catch on 'SEO', about semantic it was an info i read on a website but as i could not confirm the source, I deleted it from my answer. However it doesn't change anything to the answer.

Comment: Pal... the link you provided me in your comment for my post has this info. You should be more precise. No hard feelings tho

Comment: I never said you were wrong. When you told me, I searched again and found the real answer. The problem was the last website I looked that reversed the two things and got me wrong. My bad, my bad... You want me to be more precise about SEO ? This is not an exact science and that's why i cannot tell you **IT WILL** work but on every website I searched ( top 10 google ) it was clearly said that i should not change anything. Cannot tell you that's 100%, as nobody can know the search engines script, but that's what I found.

Comment: LOL, pal... I never said you said I'm wrong! :) Chill out. I'm glad you're trying to help - that what is really important. Thanks for this